# Can I calculate user authorization with Spring's hasAuthority without throwing/catching an exception?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authorization

My Java application uses Spring's `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SomeScopeName')")` on methods to assert that the user is authorized to perform the actions in the methods. This annotation throws an `AccessDeniedException` if the user is unauthorized:

```java
@Override
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SomeScopeName')")
public void assertHasDisplayAuthorization() {
    // empty on purpose
}
```

One of the application's endpoints wants to inform the user interface about which actions the user is able to perform. For that, it calculates an `Authorizations` object that renders as JSON like `{ canDisplay: true, canEdit: false, ... }`:

```java
public Authorizations getAuthorizations() {
    return new Authorizations(hasDisplayAuthorization(), hasEditAuthorization(), ...);
}
```

That calculation calls the `@PreAuthorize`'d methods to determine the user's authorization:

```java
private boolean hasDisplayAuthorization() {
    try {
        validator.assertHasDisplayAuthorization();
        return true;
    } catch (AccessDeniedException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This works, but I don't like the fact that I need to throw and catch an exception just to calculate a simple true/false.

Is there a possibility to calculate the `Authorizations` object without having to throw exceptions?

For example, would it be possible and reliable to calculate the authorization in an `@Value` annotation and just assign it to an object attribute?

```java
@Value("hasAuthority('SomeScopeName')")
boolean canDisplay;

... return new Authorizations(canDisplay, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `@PreAuthorize`, you can do it manually using the following class:

```java
public class SecurityHelper {
  public static boolean hasAuthority(String authority) {
    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
    return authorities.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority));
  }
}
```

Then, you can define an additional class with methods for checking each scope, for example:

```java
public class AuthorityChecker {
  public static boolean hasDisplayAuthorization(){
    return SecurityHelper.hasAuthority("SomeScopeName");
  }
  //...
}
```

Keep in mind, that it will work as long as `SecurityContext` is available in the current thread, otherwise, it will throw an exception.